# Image button slow load time in android

Tags: android, performance, scrollview, imagebutton

I am making a scrollView with a bunch of image buttons. Unfortunately this view takes a very long time to load - so much so that the user would be likely to close the app assuming it is an error.

Any ideas on how I can make this process faster?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
    <TableRow> 
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonCone"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/cone" 
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonCube"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/cube" 
            />
    </TableRow>
            <TableRow> 
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonCylinder"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/cylinder" 
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonTrapezoidalprism"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/trapezoidal_prism" 
            />
```

etc...

Comment: 12 at the moment (although I wanted to add more... might have to make a second page) - Works ok(ish) on the emulator but takes forever on the phone.

Comment: Never heard this before: emulator being faster than a device..

Comment: specify the layout height and width for Tablerows

Comment: paste the code too, maybe the slowness is due to code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem... I only had png's in the drawable-mdpi folder but not the other drawable folders. I've made copies of each png and pasted them in drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-xhdpi and now it works very quickly on the phone aswell as the emulator.

Presumably the emulator was taking the medium definition .png's but the phone wanted to take from a different resolution and wasn't able to.